# Cyclic modules over serial rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a serial ring. What can be said about the uniform dimension of cyclic $R$-modules? Specially I would like to know Is it true that every cyclic $R$-module  has finite uniform dimension ?